# The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I'm getting this error when running the command on azure release pipeline.

The pipepeline is running on premise server. I am able to execute the command from the server, yet the azure agent is unable to run it.

Here the full log:

```
2021-11-17T10:22:04.1713762Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\9283112d-f24e-4a23-a9cb-5f4a9ddbf609.ps1'"
2021-11-17T10:22:04.9965126Z VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program 
2021-11-17T10:22:04.9969014Z Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18226\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll'.
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1903160Z Invoke-Sqlcmd : The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded. 
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1904438Z For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'.
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1905465Z At C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\9283112d-f24e-4a23-a9cb-5f4a9ddbf609.ps1:5 char:1
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1906570Z + Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\azagent\A1\_work\r3\a\_main\docker-windo ...
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1907306Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1908214Z     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2021-11-17T10:22:05.1909889Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

Comment: "For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'." So... tried that already? (From the Azure script, obviously.)

Comment: I try call `Import-Module SqlServer` from the script, it return an error saying the user declined installation, but the command after, the Invoque-SqlCmd command worked nicely after. Looks some kind of weird initialization bug. The module is obviously installed. Not sure if i should post it as a answer.

Comment: If you've only just installed it, or SQL Server, you probably need to reboot the Windows host.

Comment: Could be, but is not the case. I think it is related with some initialization that happen on every account. I ran from my account and found no issues. But i found that error from the agent account. And that module was not recently installed.